# Cannot disable auto-play for each video in YouTube embed playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

```
<iframe width="763" height="448" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLD7SqVUGDdDBw_xmMKTDF5MlBwys_KlUk&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px;"></iframe>
```

When I try it embedding just a video it works, but when I disable auto-play in "embed playlist code", it doesn't work.

In first video it doesn't play automatically but when video ends, it plays the next video—I want it to stop after each video.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The `autoplay` parameter does exactly what it's supposed to do [as per documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#autoplay):

> This parameter specifies whether the initial video will automatically start to play when the player loads. Supported values are `0` or `1`. The default value is `0`.

Ending playback after each video cannot be done via just player parameters, you need to use the [IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) for that, but at this point, we're well into [Stackoverflow's `youtube-iframe-api` territory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/youtube-iframe-api).